# Multiple raster - same extent - smallest overlapping area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-statistics

Within ArcGIS (10.1) I have multiple raster files, for which I have to calculate different statistics, based on the total size of the raster.

EDIT: The raster have the same extent on a coarse scale from a visual Impression, but zooming in on a fine scale it is visible that the cells at the boundary are different. The raster have been computed with different Software products, but they have the same cell size.

I already tried to clip all raster by the same polygon of the study area boundary, but this still gives a different total size of the raster. 
The problem is that I cannot compare the raster if the total size (number of cells multiplied by the cellsize_x multiplied by the cellsize_y) for the one is 119.5 km2 and for the other 120.8 km2.

How can I calculate the smallest overlapping area of the multiple raster?

Comment: Could the problem be rooted in different cell sizes. You could rectify this by resampling.

Comment: The cell size is the same for all raster, but they have been computed with different software products, so they are different in their extent, but I need them all for the same extent. I added the Information to the question.